# Wix: Registering and then starting a Windows Service

Tags: wix

I have a situation where I have been asked to re-implement and InstallShield installer in Wix. I am having difficulty with examples on the Internet trying to implement the exact behavior. What I need to do is the following:

When the user clicks the Install button on the VerifyReadyDlg (I am using Mondo) and the ProgressDlg comes up:

- Call a .exe in the install location (if exists from a previous install)
- Stop a service in the install location (if exists from a previous install)
- Unregister the said service (if exists from a previous install)
- Copy files from the MSI, including a copy of the service .exe to install location
- Read data from some Edit controls on a previous dialog and write the data to some of the copied .xml configuration files that are now in the install location
- Register the service again

On clicking the Finish button on the very final dialog (ExitDlg) I need to:

- Start the service again
- Call an .exe (different to the first one) in the install location

I can copy files and write data to some of the files after they have been copied...though Wix just does this...I don't tell it when to go and do it. The problem is I need to schedule the first .exe call, Service Stop and Unregister before the Copy action starts and I can only Register again AFTER the .xml config files have been updated.

I have been trying to use InstallExecuteSequence and ServiceInstall elements and tying them together with CustomActions, but it's not coming together and I think I am totally approaching this the wrong way...it's not worth posting what I have done.

How should I go about this? This is a common pattern that I have seen in InstallSheild scripts, yet I can't find any Wix examples doing this sequence.

Thanks a HUGE bunch for any help on this.
Michael.

Answer (score 0):

You can control when your actions are scheduled using `Before` or `After` attributes of [Custom element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_custom.htm) or the elements for standard actions.

Is the current installation made with MSI? If yes, you may want to do *upgrade* installation and schedule [`RemoveExistingProducts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197.aspx) after you copy existing config but before other install actions are performed. This way the previous package will be removed with its own uninstall logic, and then you can install the updated package.

To save configuration from the previous version, you have to run an action before `RemoveExistingProducts` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use a Custom Action that you define in C# from a project you create that outputs to a DLL file:

```
public static class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult DoSomething(Session session) {
       // Put C# code here that does what you describe, such as run an exe 
       // from the command prompt.
       return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Import this DLL into your Wix installer:

```
<!-- The custom action DLL itself.-->
<Binary Id="WebAppCA" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)..\WebAppInstallCustomActions\bin\Debug\WebAppInstallCustomActions.CA.dll" />

<!-- The custom action that does something that you can use. -->
<CustomAction Id="DoSomething"
                  BinaryKey="WebAppCA"
                  DllEntry="DoSomething"
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Return="check" />
```

If you wanna check out a complete solution, see this thread on John Robbins' Blog ([link](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/02/23/web-application-installer-in-wix.aspx))...he has a Wix installer that installs an IIS site but when you start it, it uses a Custom Action defined in C# to enumerate a list of web sites.